build failed in react-native-android
error
Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with 
an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\chatgpt\Documents\btyu\moui\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 226 * Wh
at went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'. > Could not find method namespace() for arguments [com.swmansion.reanimat
ed] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --i
nfo or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 7s.      
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

hello everyone, I am a new developer in React-Native, I try to launch my project but I cannot, I installed all the dependencies with npm inatall successfully, but when I launch npx react-native run- android i got the error this above, any help will be appreciated

what your react-native and react-native-reanimated version?

"react-native": "^0.74.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.12.1",

Check the build.gradle version and modify it to 7.3.1.
